# ICalendar Location Web Address

Tags: icalendar

I have some calendar items that I am generating that the location for the event is a web address:

```
http://foo.com/conference-call/2
```

For example the link could be to a campfire session or something similar.

If embed a link into the location iCal (at least) just ignores the html link tag and shows it all as text.

Is there some way to accomplish this?

Thanks,

Justin

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that it is up to the receiving application to deal with all the parts of the event in the best way for that application.

So in this case, I'd say it must be a failing on iCal side.

It should not be necessary/nor approprate for the ics file to make that a hyperlink (ie offer up html instead of a url).

You could test it out in a bunch of other calendar applications - but then some do not even allow for the possibility of a separate url field (google calendar does not allow one to enter one for example, - you are expected to use the description field)